# Fast Export script of Teradata

Tags: teradata

i am trying to pull data from Teradata and put it into hadoop.

i have written a script to do so.

Well this is not a direct process.

It is staged to Hadoop's local and then put into Hadoop.

While running the script i am getting the following error:

```
0002 .LOGTABLE  log_1;
**** 16:06:28 UTY1006 CLI error: 235, MTDP: EM_GSSINITFAIL(235): call to
     gss_init failed.
**** 16:06:28 UTY2410 Total processor time used = '0 Seconds'
.       Start : 16:06:28 - TUE AUG 20, 2013
.       End   : 16:06:28 - TUE AUG 20, 2013
.       Highest return code encountered = '12'.
```

Can anyone help me and tell what is the mistake here? What does that error mean?

Comment: Before you unload loads of data from Teradata to process it somewhere else: Consider to connect your Hadoop job to Teradata via JDBC and just read what you need and when you need it. All Bi and Etl tool vendors optimize that way (they give it fancy names like push-down or in-database) This way you can make use of the full parallelism of your Teradata and minimize the traffic on your network. Why not using what your company has paid for?

Comment: To @jboi's comment - Teradata does provide a connector between Hadoop and Teradata that may help facilitate what you are trying to accomplish. You may wish to talk to the account representative.

Comment: You can find more about the Teradata / Hadoop Connector [here](http://developer.teradata.com/connectivity/articles/teradata-connector-for-hadoop-now-available). I dont know if it has a licence fee or you can just download it at developer.teradata.com.

Answer (score 1):

The system you are running the FastExport script from is either missing, has a corrupt installation of, or incorrect PATH statement for the Teradata GSS Libraries. The ICU and GSS libraries are security components for the Teradata providers (CLI, ODBC, .Net, and JDBC). Without them you will not be able to connect to the Teradata system.